# Problems with redirecting to signed cloud storage URL (cURL?)

Tags: http, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, signed-url

I am creating a Firebase HTTP function that uploads a file to Cloud Storage, creates a signed URL to the file, and then redirects the client to that URL. Using Postman with automatic redirect following turned on, the file is retrieved correctly. However, if I try to turn on redirects while using cURL (`curl -L -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://us-central1-example.cloudfunctions.net/exampleFunction" -d '{"example": true}'`), the following error is returned by Cloud Storage:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Error>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Message>
    <StringToSign>GET

application/json
1602245678
/example.appspot.com/exampleBucket/exampleFile.txt</StringToSign>
</Error>
```

If I make the request with form encoded data instead, it works in cURL as well: `curl -L "https://us-central1-example.cloudfunctions.net/exampleFunction" -d "example=true"`

If I try to manually make a GET request to the URL in Postman, I get an equivalent error:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Error>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Message>
    <StringToSign>GET


1602246219
/www.google.com/example.appspot.com/exampleBucket/exampleFile.txt</StringToSign>
</Error>
```

If I paste the URL into a browser or use cURL to download the signed URL, the file is also downloaded correctly.

I am using the following function to get the signed url:

```js
async getSignedUrl(file: File, expireAt: number): Promise<string> {
    const [url] = await file
        .getSignedUrl({
            action: "read",
            expires: expireAt
        });

    return url
}
```

which returns a signed URL in the following format:
`https://storage.googleapis.com/example.appspot.com/exampleBucket/exampleFile.txt?GoogleAccessId=[Access ID]&Expires=1602246219&Signature=[Signature]` (I've noted that the value of "Expires" is the same value returned in the  tag).

My suspicion is that Postman and cURL adds something to the request which results in a different signature, but I am not sure exactly what is going on.

What is happening when letting cURL follow the redirect or when creating a GET request in Postman, that leads to this difference in signature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Joss Barons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64340036/1680690) answer helped me in the right direction, but it is not true that the `Content-Type` has to be `application/octet-stream`. That is only used for creating a signed url that can be used for uploading a file. In my case, when creating the signed url using the Cloud Storage SDK for node, I didn't specify a `Content-Type`, so when sending a `GET` request to the signed url, it must not contain a `Content-Type` header.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, the issue arises in two scenarios

1. When hitting your CF through curl with

```
curl -L -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://us-central1-example.cloudfunctions.net/exampleFunction" -d '{"example": true}')
```

According to the [example in github](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/master/samples/generateV4UploadSignedUrl.js) in the docs [Signed URL v4](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers#storage-signed-url-object-nodejs), `'Content-Type: application/octet-stream'` should be used:

```
curl -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' --upload-file my-file '${url}'
```

I tried with the following with successfully result:

```
curl -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' -d '{"example": true}' 'https://storage.googleapis.com/...'
```

If I try with the `content-type` you shared with failed results.

2.

> If I try to manually make a GET request to the URL in Postman, I get an equivalent error:
> I tried a simple GET in postman using a Signed URL and it worked just fine

Command used in gsutil to get the signed URL:

```
 gsutil signurl -d 10m key.json gs://BUCKET/aa.png
```

Then I tried a GET on postman and worked just fine.
[image]

I also tried with a Signed URL to upload a File in Postman and worked just fine.

My thoughts are that, according to [Common MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types)

> application/octet-stream is the default value for all other cases (not textual files).

When you set the content type as application/json you specify a JSON format, but not an object or file. That's why it works with the following, since you are not specifying the header `content-type`, the default is taken `application/octet-stream`

```
curl -L "https://us-central1-example.cloudfunctions.net/exampleFunction" -d "example=true"
```